# SQL: How to create a table with a structured data type?

Tags: sql

I'd like to know how can I create an SQL table containing a column that will contain structured data, as:

```
 CREATE TABLE mytable(
 username VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL,
 user_structured_data "here the type for structured data"
 );
```

is there any way to do that? thanks.

Comment: structured data mean what?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Structured Datatype itself SQL provide structured data type. SQL provide structured data type to allow you to use data types as your information type.

SQL not provide any structured type but provide structured data type. In your following query

```
CREATE TABLE mytable(
      username VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL,
      user_structured_data TEXT "here the type for structured data long text"
);
```

This is great documentation for using a [**structured data type**](https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/data/library/techarticle/dm-0506melnyk/) as the type for a column in a regular table

Answer (score 0):

No. You have to make due with the datatypes that are supplied by your Database vendor. You can't create your own, at least not in any of the major databases.